# clarification of notation for partial derivatives

Tags: notation, partial-derivative

its been a while since i did vector calculus and i am a little bit rusty on the notation, can someone please tell me if this is true:

$\nabla_\mathbf{a} C = \dfrac{\partial C}{\partial \mathbf{a}}$

ie. the partial derivative of $C$ with respect to $\mathbf{a}$

or am i getting things mixed up?

Comment: You should be using $=$ instead of $\iff$.

Comment: thanks, changed. but is the actual expression equivalent?

Comment: Is a of norm 1?

Comment: it is a vector of real values between 0 and 1

Comment: @guskenny83 I have no idea, sorry. I've never seen the notation on the left-hand side. It might help if you add to the question where you encountered this notation.

Comment: it is in relation to the backpropagation algorithm, $C$ is the cost function, and i believe that $\nabla_a$ is the gradient of the cost function with respect to the vector of activations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both the left and the right are commonly used notations for the directional derivative of $f$ in the direction of the vector $\mathbf a$. When $f$ is differentiable, this is, of course, given by dotting the gradient of $f$ with $\mathbf a$.